# Example of function, continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, holomorphic in the unit disk but not holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't think of an example for this. It would be easy without the condition that it must be continuous everywhere, say taking $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-2}$, but this is not continuous on $\mathbb{C}$. I tried thinking of piecewise functions, but I couldn't explicitly construct one.

There is a similar problem, to find a function that is continuous in $\mathbb{C}$, holomorphic on $\{z: Im(z) > 0\}$ but not holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$, which I assume has a similar style of solution.

Comment: @Wojowu That's not continuous everywhere.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed the condition of continuity. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

E.g. try $f(z) = \max(1,|z|)$.

Comment: Great, thanks! Am I correct in thinking that we could take $ f(z) = $min( $\frac{1}{2i}(z - \bar{z}), 0$ ) for the $\{z: Im(z) > 0\}$ case?